# Recursive Function Help (Python)

Tags: python, recursion

Okay, I have made a function using a recursive funcion and it is as follows.

```
global totalExposure
totalExposure = 0 

def f(x):
    import math
    return 10 * math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):

    time = (stop-start)
    newStart = start+step

    if(time!=0):
        radiationExposure(newStart, stop, step) 
        global totalExposure
        radiation = f(start) * step
        totalExposure += radiation
        return totalExposure
    else:
        return totalExposure
```

Now, when I put in values of whole numbers, the function works fine.

```
rad = radiationExposure(0, 5, 1)
# rad = 39.1031878433
```

However, my function gives out the wrong values when I put in values of decimals.
So, how do I make my function work with decimals as well?

For example:

```
rad = radiationExposure(0, 4, 0.25)
```

Your output:
1217.5725783047335
Correct output:
1148.6783342153556

Comment: What do you expect as the output and what is wrong with the output?

Comment: Just a tip, you should put your `import` at the beginning so that it isn't called each time the function runs...

Comment: @aj8uppal The actual will happen only once import no matter how many times the statement is run. Python will not reimport a already imported module.

Comment: Nope, I get `70.7212242558`

Comment: and I get `31.61803641252658`

Comment: Using a global variable in a recursive function is kind of missing the point of recursion.

Comment: The exact value for the integration of f(x) from 0 to 4 is `31.103859398`. And the value `31.6180364125` of adsmith is correct for step size 0.25.

Answer (score 0):

I'd originally answered that it was `floordiv`'s fault, then I thought it was floating point fudging, now I think it's just bad code. Let's look a little deeper, shall we?

First of all, if you ever see `global` in your code, try VERY HARD to get rid of it. It causes buggy code like this all the time. Let's rewrite it without a `global`....

```
import math

def f(x):
    return 10 * math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):
    totalExposure = 0
    while stop-start > 0:
        totalExposure += f(start)*step # I dont' know this formula, but this
                                       # feels wrong -- maybe double check the
                                       # math here?
        start += step
    return totalExposure
```

This actually managed to get rid of the recursion too, which will save TONS of memory.

```
### DEMO ###
>>> radiationExposure(0,5,1)
39.10318784326239
>>> radiationExposure(0,4,0.25)
31.61803641252657
```

The problem as I see it is that your `global` is being saved between recursions AND BETWEEN CALLS of the function. When I ran your code the first time, I got:

```
>>> radiationExposure(0,5,1)
39.10318784326239
>>> radiationExposure(0,5,1)
78.20637568652478
```

That's clearly wrong. Not to mention, recursive formulas should call themselves, but they tend to do so in a `return` statement! To write this recursively would be something like:

```
def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):
    time = stop-start
    new_start = start+step
    radiation = f(start)*step
    if time <= 0: # <= accounts for something like (0, 3, 0.33) where it will never EXACTLY hit zero
        return radiation
        # if we're on the last tick, return one dose of radiation
    else:
        return radiation + radiationExposure(newStart,stop,step)
        # otherwise, return one dose of radiation plus all following doses
```

Comment: This is the Euler method of integration for a differential equation, here it is just integration of the function f(x), or the (trivial) differential equation y'(x)=f(x). One should compensate for the case that in `if time <= 0:` time could be substantially below zero, so in this case `f(start)*time` should be returned instead of `f(start)*step`. And then the condition could be changed to `if time <= step:`, so that the last integration step lands exactly at `stop` without overshooting and going backwards.

Answer (score 0):

First the corrected Euler integration method that is guaranteed to integrate really from start to stop and does add an additional integration point at stop-epsilon (of size step, changing the integration interval to end at stop+step) if the floating point errors sum up towards this case.

Recall that Euler integration of a differential equation y'(x)=f(x,y(x)), y(x0)=y0 proceeds by repeatedly computing

```
y=y+h*f(x,y)
x=x+h
```

In a pure integration problem there is no y in f, integrating f(x) from a to b thus initializes y=0 and repeatedly applies

```
y=y+h*f(x)
x=x+h
```

as long as x is smaller than b. In the last step, when b-h<=x<=b, set h=b-x so that the integration process ends with (floating point) precisely x=b.

```
import math

def f(x):
    return 10 * math.exp(math.log(0.5)/5.27 * x)

def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):
    totalExposure = 0
    while stop-start > 0:
        if stop-start < step:
            step = stop-start;

        totalExposure += f(start)*step 

        start += step
    return totalExposure

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print radiationExposure(0,5,1);
    print radiationExposure(0,5,0.25);
    print radiationExposure(0,5,0.1);
    print radiationExposure(0,5,0.01);
```

---

A better solution would be to use a numerical integration routine of numpy.

---

Or even better, use that the integral of this function f(x)=C*exp(A*x) is actually known via the anti-derivative F(x)=C/A*exp(C*A), so that the value is R(start,stop)=F(stop)-F(start), so

```
import math

def radiationExposure2(start, stop, dummy):
    A=math.log(0.5)/5.27;
    C=10
    return C/A*(math.exp(A*stop)-math.exp(A*start))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print radiationExposure2(0,5,1);
    print radiationExposure2(0,5,1);
```

The returned values are for the Euler integration

```
39.1031878433 (step=1)
37.2464645611 (step=0.25)
36.8822478677 (step=0.1)
36.6648587685 (step=0.01)
```

versus the numerical value of the exact integration

```
36.6407572458
```